# How do you use Amazon's Mechanical Turk API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, mechanicalturk

I'm using Amazon's Mechanical Turk as a requester and need to automate some things (specifically bonus payments).

I feel really stupid for asking this, but... how does one actually use the MTurk API? I was reading the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/Welcome.html), and it specifies some details about a lot of requests, including [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SendBonusOperation.html) for bonus payment, but there's nothing about how to actually perform such a request. I *assume* it's an HTML request, but there's no mention of which endpoints to use or how to obtain keys for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it [via the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/mturk/index.html) or via your preferred programming language, [such as Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mturk.html).

For an introduction, you could do a web search and read articles like [Tutorial: A beginner’s guide to crowdsourcing ML training data with Python and MTurk](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-a-beginners-guide-to-crowdsourcing-ml-training-data-with-python-and-mturk-d8df4bdf2977).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have an AWS account and make a call from code or the CLI. For working code examples using the API in a variety of languages, check out [mturk-code-samples on GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/mturk-code-samples). The [MTurk blog](https://blog.mturk.com/) also has end-to-end examples.